# Java considerations for running scripts on multiple OS

Tags: java, linux, macos, operating-system, portability

I'm attempting to learn java and have been developing some programs using the IDE Netbeans, Ideally i wanted to make my code portable to numerous OS platforms and have been testing on windows and OSX, both of which appears to act the same.
However when i've attempted to run them on Linux RHEL, Centos or Ubuntu even AIX i'm getting errors with the same code sample.
An example would be:

```
List<String> tstList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Works in windows/OSX but not in rhel linux, i'm assuming it needs the "String" defined after the ArrayList??:

```
List<String> tstList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I understand there's differences, but assumed that the java packages catered for that..

SO My questions are: Is there general considerations that people should take when writing for portability? 
Is there a standard package, or instructions, or something to make java code portability easy?

Or is the whole point to write your own methods to only run on specific OS's??

Comment: The example you provided is actually to do with the JDK version you are compiling against

Comment: What versions of Java are you compiling against?  The diamond notation you're using will require 7 or later, regardless of where you compile it.

Comment: You say it doesn't work - what doesn't work? Error messages? Different output?

Answer (score 2):

Earlier java versions need to describe your type but 7 and 7+ versions do not need that. Check your version of jdk